# How to use telekinesis on a creature (Savage Worlds)

Tags: savage-worlds, savage-worlds-adventure-edition

I'm trying to understand how a character can use telekinesis to move another creature. It says:

> Telekinesis is the ability to move objects or creatures (including oneself) with arcane will. It has a Strength of d10, or d12 with a raise.
>
> Unwilling opponents resist the caster’s arcane skill with an opposed Spirit roll when targeted and at the start of each of their turns afterward until they’re released. They can be moved up to the caster’s Smarts per turn in any direction, and can be bashed into walls, ceilings, or other obstacles for Str+d6 damage. Dropped creatures suffer falling dam­age as usual.

According to the encumbrance chart on page 67, a d10 ("It has a Strength of d10...") is only enough to carry up to 80 lbs. Does that mean that a creature moved by telekinesis has to weight 80 lbs or less, or is there a different table that we use to know how much it can lift?

Are they considered to be bound and/or entangled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Two Questions

The first issue is Encumbrance. Characters can lift up to ***four times*** the value on the table.

> The maximum weight a character can lift or carry is four times the listed weight.

As long as the creature being lifted is less than 320 pounds, weight is not a concern.

The target is neither Entangled nor Bound. If they were then the power would mention it. Similarly, if it worked like Grappling then it would reference those rules. 
 Instead, the victim is grabbed by the power and can be moved by the power user. The power says nothing about interfering with the victim's ability to move - though common sense indicates that a creature moved into midair prevents that character from moving in a conventional manner.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thank you!